# Decomposition of an unitary operator by simple operators

Tags: matrices, group-theory, lie-groups, mathematical-physics, tensor-products

For quantum computation, it's well known that any unitary operator can be approximated with an arbitrary accuracy by simple operators, for example to approximate an unitary operator on n qubits by no more than $e^n$ universal gates.

What's puzzling me is that: Can we decompose an unitary operator into no more than $e^n$ (or with a similar complexity) simple unitary operators, i.e., as a tensor product of simple unitary operators? Here I am not talking about 'approximation' but a precise 'decomposition'. Also the simple operators need not to be from a finite set as in the universal gate case, we can use any simple operators (for example any 2-level unitary operator).

So I want to have $U=U_1U_2....U_k$, where $U_{i}=I\otimes I \otimes I ...\otimes O_{i1,i2}..\otimes I$. $I$ is the identical operator on a single qubit and $O_{i1,i2}$ is an arbitrary two-level operator on qubit $i1,i2$. Can such kind of decomposition possible? What's the complexity of it, i.e., $k \sim O(e^n)$? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is $e$ Euler's number, as in $e \approx 2.718?$

Comment: Cross-posted to physics.se: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/201770.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, such a kind of *exact* decomposition is always possible.  This is shown in [Barenco *et al.*, Elementary gates for quantum computation](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9503016) (Sec. 8, pg. 27 in the arXiv preprint), based on work by [Reck *et al.*](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.73.58) (which gives a corresponding decomposition where each elementary operation is the identity except for a $2\times 2$ *submatrix*).  The construction given requires $O(n^34^n)$ two-qubit gates.

(This is the same answer as to the cross-post https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/201770).

Comment: Does this mean we can estimate the complexity of a quantum operation, at least an upper limit of the complexity by the decomposition? Or we can reach any point $U \in SU(2^n)$ from $I$ by a (non-smooth due to the discrete 'gate' but not a continuous Hamiltonian $H(t)$) curve $U(t)$ with a finite length and the 'velocity' $U'(t)$ falls only in a subspace of the Lie algebra of $SU(2^n)$ since only 2-bit operations are allowed? It's still out of my intuition. it seems to claim you can reach any point in a 3D space but you are only allowed to move in X direction.  Something wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Again. If the (upper limit of) complexity of the exact implementation is $O(n^34^n)$, still we see it's different from the common sense that the complexity of a typical state is $e^n$. Do you think this difference will lead to any observable effect? For example, Susskind considered the ERB volume as a consequence of the state complexity and he use $e^n$ for the maximal complexity. Should this be modified accordingly?

Comment: A general $n$-qubit unitary has $4^n$ parameters.  Each two-qubit gates needs a fixed number of parameters, so we need at least $O(4^n)$ of those to realize it.  I would say the right analogy is that we can reach any point in 3D space by moving in X, Y, or Z direction.  --  Regarding states, I would guess that their complexity is correspondingly $O(2^n)$.  I would suspect that $e^n$ is just meant to indicate exponential scaling in $n$, and the basis might depend on the context.  Maybe you can give a precise reference (and possibly ask a different question)?

Comment: Thanks. Here are some references that I am interested in. [Ref1](http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.02287); [Ref2](http://arxiv.org/abs/1411.0690); [Ref3](http://arxiv.org/abs/1408.2823). It's related to the work of Nielsen as explained in the papers.

Comment: In fact I was considering that if only simple Hamiltonian is allowed(so we can only evolve with H in a subspace of the Lie algebra of $SU(2^n)$), why each unitary operator can be achieved with a finite complexity?  I believe in this case it's true, but I need to figure out the details. Maybe the exact complexity may not be that important as far as it's finite. I was wondering if there is a possibility that some states may have infinite complexity. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: Still I'm curious about the relationship between the simple Hamiltonian and the Lie algebra of $SU(2^n)$.  The simple Hamiltonian is a subset of the Lie algebra of $SU(2^n)$, how it can reach any point in $SU(2^n)$? There should be a diffeomorphism between the Lie algebra of $SU(2^n)$ and $SU(2^n)$, why it's also true for a subset of the Lie algebra of $SU(2^n)$?

Comment: If you have further questions, you should post them as independent questions.  Questions should not be asked in comments.

Answer (score 0):

The possibility of what you want to do would imply, at the very least, that every unitary operator on $k$ systems can be written as a "simple tensor", i.e. that we could write $U = U_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes U_k$ *some* unitary operators $U_1, \dots, U_k$.

This, however, is not the case. For example, consider $U \in \Bbb C^{2 \times 2} \otimes \Bbb C^{2 \times 2}$ to be defined by
$$
U(e_i \otimes e_j) = e_j \otimes e_i
$$
In particular, we have
$$
U = 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc|cc}
1&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
\hline
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{array}
\right]
$$
Note that there are *no* unitary matrices $U_1,U_2$ such that $U = U_1 \otimes U_2$, since the blocks are not all multiples of the same $2 \times 2$ matrix.

Comment: I think the situation is different since here I am thinking a successive implementation of multiple simple operators, I think it's different with the decomposition into tensor product. Here we are working in a more free way. Thanks.

Comment: The product of simple operators is a simple operator

Comment: Yes. I mean we allow more complex operations to achieve U than just a tensor product. We allow successive implementation of different such tensor products.  Right?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom A simple operator acts non-trivially on any two compnents in the tensor product, e.g. components 1&2 or 2&3.  The product of the latter two thus acts non-trivially on components 1, 2, and 3, and is thus no longer simple.